# Lot of GC, Android monitor sawtooth = Memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Here is my memory monitor:
[image]

I suspected a memory issue into my own project. But I decided to test with a new blank project into Android Studio and launched it, then don't touch anything. And it's the same issue.

My logcat:

```
08-27 09:25:36.909    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 385K, 15% free 3118K/3664K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
08-27 09:25:37.773    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 407K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-27 09:25:38.561    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-27 09:25:39.317    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-27 09:25:40.101    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-27 09:25:40.909    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
08-27 09:25:41.685    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-27 09:25:42.365    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-27 09:25:43.141    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
08-27 09:25:43.973    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-27 09:25:44.629    1276-1288/**** D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4    08K, 16% free 3102K/3676K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
```

Into my Android Monitor, Memory analyser:
[image]

I have 0 lines of code of my own into this new project, it's a brand new generated by Android Studio. I'm running a virtual device (Android Emulator) 4.0.3 x86. It's the same with my Nexus 5 or a Genymotion.

Is that normal?

**Edit**

Thanks to the answer of Jiang YD and weston, I investigate deeper the issue with the memory heap:

[image]

So all the allocation are coming mainly from dumpGfxInfo(). 
Thanks to this information I was able to find similar post on StackOverFlow: [Android: Constant memory consumption / dumpGfxInfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024555/android-constant-memory-consumption-dumpgfxinfo) and it seems to be an issue with Android Studio, which is log here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182869

**Edit 2**

It's now fixed into the Android Studio 1.4 beta

Comment: seems only the debugger thread monitoring is working, because it is a blank activity. so the allocation may made by the debugger. can you check that what in the heap?

Comment: Thanks, you helped with your tips! I edit my original post (it's related to a bug in Android Studio: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182869)

Comment: yes, so it is a debugger thing :)

Comment: And it's now fixed! Into the 1.4 beta

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's only a Memory leak if the consumed memory is going up over time. These graphs don't exhibit that.

Secondly, I think the memory saw tooth pattern must be normal. Your first graph has larger peaks-and-troughs so it points to additional allocations done by your project over the empty project, but it's not that helpful a view for actually tracking down the allocation and garbage collection problems.

A better option is in the android device monitor, the allocation tracker:

[image: Allocation Tracker]

Click start tracking and then get allocations. You will see what was allocated in that period. Clicking each entry gives call stack for the allocation.

You can use this to see what's happening with the empty project and also see what's up with yours.

Comment: Thanks, you helped with your tips! I edit my original post (it's related to a bug in Android Studio: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182869)