# Changing from 1 activity to another is really really slow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio, start-activity

This is the code that I used:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(PSTimelineActivity.this, PSPreCheckoutActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("checkout", 0);
                            startActivity(i);
```

And it takes around 5-6 seconds to change the activity. Time in which my console log is flooded by the same error, tens of times:

```
  09-10 15:56:16.661  31171-31189/nl.hgrams.passenger W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.HardwareRenderer android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer' on a null object reference
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1086)
        at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:546)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

TRACEVIEW doesn't help, because of the services that work in the background of the app.
I added some logs, for the next Activity, at the start and end of `OnCreate()` and `OnResume()`, and it enters here, logs them, and only after, I get flooded by the error. And the `View` comes to the screen only after the errors finish. Which is weird. because at `OnResume()` I should have had the view already correct?

```
 09-10 16:16:45.722  18674-18674/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ BINDER here started activity
 09-10 16:16:45.798  18674-18674/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ BINDER onCreate 1
 09-10 16:16:45.813  18674-18674/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ BINDER onCreate 2
 09-10 16:16:45.819  18674-18674/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ BINDER onResume 1
 09-10 16:16:45.836  18674-18674/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ BINDER onResume 2
 09-10 16:16:45.914  18674-18857/nl.hgrams.passenger W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.HardwareRenderer android.view.View$AttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer' on a null object reference
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.dumpGfxInfo(WindowManagerGlobal.java:476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.dumpGfxInfo(ActivityThread.java:1086)
        at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:546)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

The error might be in my `OnCreate()` function, even something might be called on a separate `thread` and that causes the error.

This is my `OnCreate()` function, if it helps:
http://pastebin.com/1ajdzSr2

**EDIT:** After some more test, I figured out that it hangs on the init function that I call from my `OnResume()` method.
My `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    CheckOutIntent cot = PSLocationCenter.getInstance().pref.getOutIntent(PSPreCheckoutActivity.this);
    if( cot != null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(PSPreCheckoutActivity.this, PSTimelineActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    PSLocationCenter.getInstance().pref.setIsBackground(this, false);
    if(!PSLocationCenter.getInstance().mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        PSLocationCenter.getInstance().startLocationClient();
    }
    init();
}
```

NOW this is my `init()` Function:
I created it specially in a AsyncTask, to that it won't use the UI Thread.
BUT inside, at a moment, I use realm, which must be on the main thread, so I make a Handler post. Might this be the problem? I'm still debugging , but I'm guessing it might be there.
PS: Will it help if I remove the Asynctask?

```
 public void init(){
    loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.subheader).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeSearchKeyboard();
        }
    });
    AsyncTask initAsync = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            if(checkout == 2){
                Log.i("","PSPreCheckoutActivity checkout 2");
                if(PSLocationCenter.getInstance().mLocationClient.isConnected()){
                    try {
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(PSPreCheckoutActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                        List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                        if (address.size() > 0) {
                            if(tripName != null){
                                currentPlace = new Destination("google", null, null, null, tripName, loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude() ,  (String.format(address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) : "") + ", " + address.get(0).getLocality()), false, false, null);
                            }else{
                                currentPlace = new Destination("google", null, null, null, String.format(address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) : ""), loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude() ,  (String.format(address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) : "") + ", " + address.get(0).getLocality()), false, false, null);
                            }
                        }
                        WillGetNearestData();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        currentPlace = new Destination("nointerneterror", null, null, null, "nointerneterror", 0,0 , "nointerneterror", false, false, null);
                        WillGetNearestData();
                        Log.i("", "precheckout error: " + e.getMessage());
                        Utils.appendLog("precheckout error: " + e.getMessage());
                        if(e.getMessage().contains("Timed out")){
                            AlertDialog.show(PSPreCheckoutActivity.this, getString(R.string.Error), e.getMessage(), getString(R.string.OK), null);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    try {
                        PSLocationCenter.getInstance().startLocationClient();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        init();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e("", "precheckout init error is: " + e.getMessage());
                        if(e.getMessage().contains("Timed out")){
                            AlertDialog.show(PSPreCheckoutActivity.this, getString(R.string.Error), e.getMessage(), getString(R.string.OK), null);
                        }
                        init();
                    }

                }
            }else{
                Log.i("","PSPreCheckoutActivity checkout not 2");
                Handler han = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                han.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        PSTrip psTrip = PSTripDBFactory.getInstance(PSPreCheckoutActivity.this).getActiveTrip();
                        if(psTrip != null){
                            Destination destination = psTrip.getDestination();
                            LatLng finishLocation = new LatLng(PSLocationCenter.getInstance().locEnd.getLatitude(), PSLocationCenter.getInstance().locEnd.getLongitude());
                            if(destination != null) {
                                isRoaming = false;
                                finishLocation = new LatLng(psTrip.getDestination().getLat(), psTrip.getDestination().getLon());
                            }else{
                                isRoaming = true;
                            }
                            if(PSLocationCenter.getInstance().mLocationClient.isConnected()){
                                if(checkout != 2){
                                    loc = new Location("");
                                    loc.setLatitude(LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(PSLocationCenter.getInstance().mLocationClient).getLatitude());
                                    loc.setLongitude(LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(PSLocationCenter.getInstance().mLocationClient).getLongitude());
                                }
                                try {
                                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(PSPreCheckoutActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                                    List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                                    if (address.size() > 0) {
                                        if(tripName != null){
                                            currentPlace = new Destination("google", null, null, null, tripName, loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude() ,  (String.format(address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) : "") + ", " + address.get(0).getLocality()), false, false, null);
                                        }else{
                                            currentPlace = new Destination("google", null, null, null, String.format(address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) : ""), loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude() ,  (String.format(address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) : "") + ", " + address.get(0).getLocality()), false, false, null);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    Log.i("","precheckout error: " + e.getMessage());
                                    Utils.appendLog("precheckout error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                                LatLng locLatLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
                                if(Utils.distanceBetween2Points(locLatLng, finishLocation) < 250 && !isRoaming){ //TODO will have to be 250, now 9000 for hardcoded values to be seen all the time
                                    isNearby = true;
                                    plannedDestination = destination;
                                }
                                WillGetNearestData();
                            }else{
                                try {
                                    PSLocationCenter.getInstance().startLocationClient();
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    init();
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    Log.e("","precheckout init 2 error is: " + e.getMessage());
                                    init();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
        }
    };
    initAsync.execute();
}
```

Comment: "And it takes around 5-6 seconds to change the activity" -- use Traceview to determine where your problem lies.

Comment: Are you using a service ? I'm saying because of the binder mentioned in your trace. Remember that services run on the main thread...

Comment: Yes, I have services that run on the background. BUT I have other intents to other activities, which work good, having no issues with the transition from one to another.
@CommonsWare I tried with TraceView BUT, having services on the background, they consume most of my CPU's memory, and I can't figure out, what's wrong cause of that :) And cause other activities are changed much much quicker, I consider that the services are not a problem

Comment: @CommonsWare I just love the people that come, say something on a sarcastic tone, and then just downvote. Not everybody is a specialist like you. Some just try to get by :)
And like I said Traceview doesn't help with shit. Not even the debugger, cause it blocks the app and one moment in Looper.java, and I'm forced to close it.... so any suggestions?

Comment: "I just love the people that come, say something on a sarcastic tone, and then just downvote" -- I did not downvote you. But, to avoid this problem, I will avoid your questions in the future.

Comment: sorry for that then, my mistake, just had a bad day

Comment: @rosualin the layout traversal that eventually results in something being displayed on the screen happens asynchronously to the activity lifecycle methods, i.e. just because `onResume` finished doesn't mean anything is displayed yet. You might need to show more of your PSPreCheckoutActivity class.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out already. Slowly I'm commenting out parts of my code, in order to see where it hangs

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024555/android-constant-memory-consumption-dumpgfxinfo)?

Comment: @ci_  Thanks a lot, I was on Android Studio 1.4 Preview, updated now to Beta3 and will test again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ci_ I found out the issue. This is apparently a bug of Android Studio 1.4 Preview. or the Android SDK.
For more details, check here:
[Android: Constant memory consumption / dumpGfxInfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024555/android-constant-memory-consumption-dumpgfxinfo)
That helped me resolve it