# Android Studio memory monitor shows memory increasing

Tags: android-studio, memory, memory-leaks, monitor

I was profiling the memory of my Android app via the Android Studio memory monitor (no crashes, just checking) and noticed that it keeps growing until about 25MB until GC collection reduces it to 16MB, and then the same things happens again (see attached image below).

I decided to remove absolutely all method calls, and leave out the main activity (the one and only of my app) completely empty (i.e. onPause, onResume have no logic at all), and my app is just a blank white screen, and yet I am seeing this heap memory constant growth for some weird reason. Does anybody have an idea what's going on, or how can I further investigate this?

[Android memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njJWF.png)

Unfortunately, I still have not figured out what's going on. As I mentioned above, I have cleared everything, deleted all files and resources I had. Currently my app looks like this:

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wow.memorytest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wow.memorytest">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name="com.wow.memorytest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.wow.memorytest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in another stack overflow post.

TL;DR Pause the GPU monitor

More info here:
[Android: Constant memory consumption / dumpGfxInfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024555/android-constant-memory-consumption-dumpgfxinfo)

Comment: Then you should delete your question if it's a duplicate of another.