# GPU profiler, Android studio 3.0

Tags: android, profiling, android-studio-3.0

Recently was released Android Studio 3.0.

There are changes regarding Profiling (CPU, Network, Memory).

And with these changes came questions like:

- Where is **GPU** profiling?
- Have Google ditched it?
- Does it mean that we can only debug it only through device?

Answer (score 1):

GPU profiling [was removed from Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html).

> This tool was removed in Android Studio 3.0.

It seems the GPU monitor would [interfere in the Memory monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36345160/532368) readings when running, so that could be one of the reasons for why it was removed. Personally I had it disabled most of the time because of this.

And yes, so far the only way I'm aware of debugging it, [is on-device](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering.html).

Comment: Hello, on-device GPU profiling is not good. It is not opening in games. How can we open it in games?

Comment: @gurkan-stack 
In games ? The GPU profiler we used to have on Android Studio (and now only on-device) is only for Android 2D rendering engine. So every thing down to drawing on a canvas. It does not cover Open GL drawing requests. And I don't know where you can have something similar for that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hello!Hello! you can use [“Android GPU Inspector (AGI)”](https://developer.android.com/agi) to check GPU performance.